# Reading from instantiated Java array throwing NullPointerException instead of returning 0

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I've made the following class just to make clear what I don't understand, it's not actually going to be used for anything.

```
public class A
{
    private int[] items;

    public A()
    {
        int[] items = new int[7];
    }

    public int first()
    {
        return items[0];
    }
}
```

So when we create a new instance of A, the array "items" will become an array with a capacity of 7.

When calling the first() method, it asks for the value of the int-variable in the first position of the array. Since we haven't given this int an actual value, according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html the default value that will be stored is "0".

Yet when I actually call the method, instead of returning 0, I receive a nullpointerexception. Why is this?

[Edit]
Can't reply to the comments on my own question for some reason...
But thanks for your help!
If someone else has a similar problem and it's still not quite clear what went wrong:

I've declared but not initialized a variable "items" which can hold an array of integers.
Now, in the constructor, instead of initializing my original variable I've just declared a new variable "items" (which only exists in the constructor and then disappears) and then initialized it to be an array for 7 integers.
Now when calling the "first" method it tries to find what is on the first location of my original "items" array, since that is the only "items" array that currently exists. But I haven't initialized that array, which means there is no array, only a variable. Because of that a nullpointerexception is returned.

Comment: No, you're shadowing your field.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
public A()
{
    int[] items = new int[7];
}
```

should be

```
public A()
{
    this.items = new int[7];
}
```

otherwise you're declaring and initializing a different variable with the same name as your instance field.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int[] items = new int[7];
```

as

```
this.items = new int[7];
```